# Firebase Cloud Function error when trying to get parameter

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am having trouble getting the parameters of onWrite trigger. Here is my function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.afterCourseAdded = functions.database.ref('/course/{courseId}').onWrite((context, event) => {
    const uid = event.params.uid;
    const courseId = context.params.courseId;
    console.log('User ' + event.params.email + ' created course' + courseId);
    const promise1 = admin.database().ref('/course/' + courseId + '/lect').set(uid);
    return Promise.all([promise1]);
});
```

Users are writing data this way:
course
    |_ Course Name
               |_ descr: "some description"

After the data is written, the function must write the uid of the user as "lect" property:
course
    |_ Course Name
               |_ descr: "some description"
               |_ lect: "some UID"
The error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'courseId' of undefined
    at exports.afterCourseAdded.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:19:36)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:779:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Line 19 is:

```
const courseId = context.params.courseId;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Update 1:
Function:

```
exports.afterCourseAdded = functions.database.ref('/course/{courseId}').onWrite((change, context) => {
    // Only edit data when it is first created.
    if (change.before.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    // Exit when the data is deleted.
    if (!change.after.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    const uid = context.params.uid;
    const courseId = context.params.courseId;
    console.log('User ' + context.params.email + ' created course' + courseId);
    const promise1 = admin.database().ref('/course/' + courseId + '/lect').set(uid);
    return Promise.all([promise1]);
});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined
    at exports.afterCourseAdded.functions.database.ref.onWrite.context (/user_code/index.js:18:31)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:779:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Comment: Could you explain why your first parameter is called `context` and the second one is called `event`?  The names don't seem to match what you're actually going to receive for an onWrite callback.

Comment: If you're using the latest version of firebase cloud function(1.0) then onWrite should have `(change, context)` see the firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value.

Comment: I have just updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
exports.afterCourseAdded = functions.database.ref('/course/{courseId}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {

    // Leave this part out if you want this trigger to work for updates
    if (change.before.exists()) {
        return null;
    }
    // Exit when the data is deleted.
    if (!change.after.exists()) { //This checks if its a delete event
       return null;
    }
    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database
    const writtenContent = change.after.val();
    const uid = writtenContent.uid;//This line assumes that the uid field already exists in the node
    const courseId = context.params.courseId;
    console.log('User ' + writtenContent.email + ' created course' + courseId);
    const promise1 = admin.database().ref('/course/' + courseId + '/lect').set(uid);
    return Promise.all([promise1]);
});
```

Comment: You should use the` onCreate ` listener if you only need to listen for new courses

Comment: @A. Newbie use `const uid = context.auth ? context.auth.uid : null;` if you are trying to get the uid of the currently looged in user. It would be set to null if a write is done to the node directly on the database or if the write isn't performed by a logged in user

Comment: Glad i could help.